# Poderiam me explicar a parte construtora por favor, não entendi

Tags: javascript

```
class Negociacao {

    **constructor(_data, _quantidade, _valor) {
        Object.assign(this, {
            _quantidade, 
            _valor
        });
        this._data = new Date(_data.getTime())
        Object.freeze(this);
    }**

    getVolume() {
        return this._quantidade * this._valor;
    }

    getData() {
        return new Date(this._data.getTime());
    }

    getQuantidade() {
        return this._quantidade;
    }

    getValor() {
        return this._valor;
    }

}
```

Comment: aonde você esse código?

Answer (score 0):

analizando o construtor abaixo, o que acontece:

```
    constructor(_data, _quantidade, _valor) {
        Object.assign(this, {
            _quantidade, 
            _valor
        });
        this._data = new Date(_data.getTime())
        Object.freeze(this);
    }
```

1. São passados 3 valores para este construtor, _data, _quantidade e _valor.
2. O método Object.assign(), atribui a this, no caso a classe Negociacao, os valores _quantidade e _valor (que na estrutura de classes, são atributos do objeto).
3. Atribui a classe o valor de _data.
4. O método Object.freeze(), congela o objeto, ou seja, não são permitidas mais modificações dos atributos fora do construtor.

Então, como conclusão, este construtor atribui valores iniciais para a classe Negociacao e a congela, para que novos valores não possam ser inputados após a construção da classe.

Referêcias:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze